# Why VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UNORM textures are not displaying correctly using Vulkan/Android?

Tags: android, c++, vulkan

I am trying to display a simple textured quad (no Alpha channnel) using Vulkan on Android and can't get to work. Yet, the same exact code path displays the texture properly if I add the alpha channel and change the format to VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM.

Here's the main points for the code that works.

Image creation.

```
VkImageCreateInfo imageCreateInfo = {};
imageCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
imageCreateInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
imageCreateInfo.extent.width = width;
imageCreateInfo.extent.height = height;
imageCreateInfo.extent.depth = 1;
imageCreateInfo.mipLevels = 1;
imageCreateInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
imageCreateInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
imageCreateInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
imageCreateInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
imageCreateInfo.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
imageCreateInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
imageCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
```

the texture (hardcoded as C)

```
static const unsigned char tiny44[] = {
0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff, 0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff, 0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff, 0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff, 0x00,0xff,0x00,0xff, 0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff, 0x00,0xff,0x00,0xff,
0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff, 0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff, 0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff, 0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff, 0xff,0x00,0xff,0xff, 0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff, 0x00,0xff,0xff,0xff,
};
static int32_t currWidth = 4;
static int32_t currHeight = 4;
static uint32_t imageSize = sizeof(tiny44);
```

When I map the image and copy to GPU memory

```
vkMapMemory(mainDevice.logicalDevice, imageStagingBufferMemory, 0, imageSize, 0, &data);
memcpy(data, imageData, static_cast<size_t>(imageSize));
vkUnmapMemory(mainDevice.logicalDevice, imageStagingBufferMemory);
```

ImageView Creation

```
    VkImageViewCreateInfo viewCreateInfo = {};
    viewCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    viewCreateInfo.image = image;   // Image to create view for
    viewCreateInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;    // Type of image (1D, 2D, 3D, Cube, etc)
    viewCreateInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM; // Format of image data
```

the resulting image after rendering (correct)

[image]

the code below shows how I changed the data (exact same texture less the alpha channel) and the creation fuction.

```
static const unsigned char tiny44_no_alpha[] = {
0xff,0x00,0x00, 0xff,0xff,0xff, 0xff,0x00,0x00, 0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff, 0x00,0xff,0x00, 0xff,0xff,0xff, 0x00,0xff,0x00,
0x00,0x00,0xff, 0xff,0xff,0xff, 0x00,0x00,0xff, 0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff, 0xff,0x00,0xff, 0xff,0xff,0xff, 0x00,0xff,0xff,
};

static int32_t currWidth = 4;
static int32_t currHeight = 4;
static uint32_t imageSize = sizeof(tiny44_no_alpha);
```

creation function

```
VkImageCreateInfo imageCreateInfo = {};
imageCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
imageCreateInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
imageCreateInfo.extent.width = width;
imageCreateInfo.extent.height = height;
imageCreateInfo.extent.depth = 1;
imageCreateInfo.mipLevels = 1;
imageCreateInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
imageCreateInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UNORM;    // the only difference
imageCreateInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
imageCreateInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
imageCreateInfo.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
imageCreateInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
imageCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
```

the mapping calls are identical since I just swap the bytes and new sizes. Yet, this is what I get now:

[image]

Can anyone spot the bug? Do I have to do anything else besides change the VkImageCreateInfo, VkImageViewCreateInfo and update the raw data and its size when mapping to GPU memory?

thank you.

Comment: Did you verify that the image format was allowed to be used by your GPU for that usage? Unlike 4 channel formats, these 3-channel formats are not *required* to be available for use in any capacity.

Comment: Usual comment - do validation layers show any problems?

Even if supported, RGB8 data can often have alignment and padding requirements - check the subresource layout for e.g. row pitch that includes padding.

Comment: @NicolBolas how do I find out if this format is valid? I can't find any example of how to sue 'vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties' I can get vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(mainDevice.physicalDevice, &deviceProperties); easily, but I am not sure how to enumerate the valid texture formats. Any sample I could take a look? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy image data to the GPU like the code below:

```
uint8_t *dst = data;
uint8_t *src = &tiny44_no_alpha;
uint32_t dstStride = mem_reqs.size/4;
uint32_t srcStride = 12;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    memcpy(dst, src, srcStride);
    dst += dstStride;
    src += srcStride;
}
```

Comment: I think my issue was it was not really available with the Samsung Galaxy s23, but I will try it. thx.