# What is the process for uploading raw pixels into an image texture using the rust vulkano library?

Tags: rust, textures, vulkan

I am trying to upload a PNG into the GPU using the vulkano rust library for vulkan.  I can't even create the image correctly.

The non-working code I have so far (using the 94f50f18bd25971ea123adb8b5782ad65a8f085c commit because I eventually need opengl interop) is

```
let extent = [width, height, 1];
let format = Format::R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
let image = Image::new(
    memory_allocator.clone(),
    ImageCreateInfo {
        image_type: ImageType::Dim2d,
        format,
        extent,
        usage: ImageUsage::TRANSFER_DST | ImageUsage::SAMPLED,
        ..Default::default()
    },
    AllocationCreateInfo {
        memory_type_filter: MemoryTypeFilter {
            required_flags: MemoryPropertyFlags::HOST_VISIBLE,
            preferred_flags: MemoryPropertyFlags::DEVICE_LOCAL,
            not_preferred_flags: MemoryPropertyFlags::empty(),
        },
        ..Default::default()
    },
)
.unwrap();
```

It fails with "called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: a non-validation error occurred: allocating memory for the image failed".  I have managed to get a couple of different errors by experimenting with different creation parameters.

What is the correct technique for creating an image that can receive raw pixels (decoded from a PNG in my case) and then used with a sampler for texture-mapped polygons?

Answer (score 1):

First you should verify that width and height are both non-zero at the time you try to create the image.

If that's not the cause, then you should probably enable the validation layers in your instance and put a breakpoint in the debug callback, so that you can see what error the underlying system is encountering that prevents image creation.

Second, this memory filter doesn't make a lot of sense:

```rust
   AllocationCreateInfo {
        memory_type_filter: MemoryTypeFilter {
            required_flags: MemoryPropertyFlags::HOST_VISIBLE,
            preferred_flags: MemoryPropertyFlags::DEVICE_LOCAL,
            not_preferred_flags: MemoryPropertyFlags::empty(),
        },
        ..Default::default()
    },
```

In general, for performance reasons, images NEED to be device local. So your preferred and required flags look backwards.  However, I get what you're trying to do, you need to be able to copy the PNG data from CPU memory to the device memory, and for that you need host-visible memory.

In general, Vulkan environments break down broadly into two categories, ones with unified memory architecture (mobile and many laptops) and ones with discrete memory architecture (desktop systems with plugin GPU cards).

On unified memory architecture, you should reverse the flags you're using to make `DEVICE_LOCAL` required and `HOST_VISIBLE` preferred (or required if you know that you have at least one memory pool that supports it).  In theory you should get back some memory that can be mapped to a CPU visible pointer at which point you can copy the PNG contents.

On most desktop systems however, loading up an image (or a buffer) into the GPU is a multi-step process that involves creating two objects, call them *A* and *B*.

*A* the actual GPU resources which will have `DEVICE_LOCAL` memory and another transient object for staging.

*B* is a second object is created with `HOST_VISIBLE` as the required memory type (and doesn't specify `DEVICE_LOCAL` at all).  You create it, map the memory to the CPU, copy your data to it.

Once *A* and *B* are both created, you need to execute a command buffer that tells the driver to copy the contents of *B* into *A*.

After the command buffer completes on the GPU, you can destroy object *B* or reuse it for some other copy, if it's generic enough.

Comment: I spent a lot of time in RustRover debugging into the vulkano source and its validation layers before I posted this question.  I did not have enough understanding of all the relevant bits to figure out how to solve the problem using just the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found

https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano/blob/94f50f18bd25971ea123adb8b5782ad65a8f085c/examples/image/main.rs#L224

which includes the following code:

```
    let texture = {
    let png_bytes = include_bytes!("image_img.png").as_slice();
    let decoder = png::Decoder::new(png_bytes);
    let mut reader = decoder.read_info().unwrap();
    let info = reader.info();
    let extent = [info.width, info.height, 1];

    let upload_buffer = Buffer::new_slice(
        memory_allocator.clone(),
        BufferCreateInfo {
            usage: BufferUsage::TRANSFER_SRC,
            ..Default::default()
        },
        AllocationCreateInfo {
            memory_type_filter: MemoryTypeFilter::PREFER_HOST
                | MemoryTypeFilter::HOST_SEQUENTIAL_WRITE,
            ..Default::default()
        },
        (info.width * info.height * 4) as DeviceSize,
    )
    .unwrap();

    reader
        .next_frame(&mut upload_buffer.write().unwrap())
        .unwrap();

    let image = Image::new(
        memory_allocator,
        ImageCreateInfo {
            image_type: ImageType::Dim2d,
            format: Format::R8G8B8A8_SRGB,
            extent,
            usage: ImageUsage::TRANSFER_DST | ImageUsage::SAMPLED,
            ..Default::default()
        },
        AllocationCreateInfo::default(),
    )
    .unwrap();

    uploads
        .copy_buffer_to_image(CopyBufferToImageInfo::buffer_image(
            upload_buffer,
            image.clone(),
        ))
        .unwrap();

    ImageView::new_default(image).unwrap()
};
```

An important thing to note is that the copy is not complete until the `uploads` command queue is complete.  Filling the `upload_buffer` will also be more complicated if the source pixels do not have an identical layout to the image (maybe RGB -vs- RGBA).

Comment: If you're doing this as part of an initialization step, you can use `VkQueue::waitIdle` and `VkDevice::waitIdle` to ensure that the upload has completed once you've submitted it.  Additionally you can deal with pixel format differences by creating a host visible image of the format you have and using vkCmdCopyImage instead of vkCmdCopyBufferToImage.

Comment: @Jherico, can you link to an example of the vkCmdCopyImage used for format conversion? (bonus points if it uses the vulkano API)  I assume there's still a vkCmdCopyBufferToImage to get the bytes into the first image.

Comment: Sorry, you can't use `vkCmdCopyImage` between incompatible formats, like one with alpha and one without.  What you actually want is image blitting, which can cross between formats, but isn't necessarily always available for a given pair of images.  See https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/e0hsth/whats_the_best_way_to_copy_between_images_with/

Comment: Based on errors I'm getting, and the results from calling image_format_properties() I suspect my GPU does not support operating on RGB8 images, much like this fellow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75954285/why-vk-format-r8g8b8-unorm-textures-are-not-displaying-correctly-using-vulkan-an ; this probably disqualifies using blitting to convert from RGB to RGBA.